# Semantic Forms Show on Select in Template

Tags: mediawiki, semantic-web, mediawiki-extensions

I have MediaWiki engine and installed Semantic Forms.

On my form i have field type show on select.

In code it look like this:

```
{{{field|wifi|input type=dropdown|values=1,2|show on select=1=>1}}}

<div id="1">
{{{some parameters|}}}
</div>
```

How i can show this in my template?
I know what i can hide empty fields in template like this

```
{{#if:{{{1|}}}|{{{1}}}}}
```

But can I check values in template and show only needed fields in my template?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check for empty values you can use `{{#if:{{{field|}}}|{{{field}}}}}` for fields too.

If you want to check if a field has a certain value you can use `{{#ifeq:{{{field|}}}|CertainValue|Output if field equals CertainValue|If not}}`.

Comment: Thanks for answer!

Comment: So i can use #ifeq like this {{#ifeq:{{{field|}}}|CertainValue|Here i can show fields if CertainValue is math|If not}} ?

Comment: Thank you very much Stefan! And one more 
question :) If i have field with hold on template, when template is empty i see filed like this in my main template {{{hold on template}}} How can i check this fields and dont display them if empty? #if didnt work in this case

Comment: I have never heard of "hold on template". What is this?

Comment: Sorry "holds template" not "hold on template", my mistake. Its special type of field whitch can contain entire template. Working in conjunction
"embed in field" parametr. Here is an example     {{{field|Main|holds template}}}    {{{for template|Individual data|embed in field=Create person[Main]}}}
{| class="formtable"
| First name:
| {{{field|First name|input type=text|size=25}}}
| Middle name:
| {{{field|Middle name|input type=text|size=25}}}
| Last name:
| {{{field|Last name|input type=text|size=25}}}
{{{end template}}}

Comment: I think I didn't use it so far, so I'm not familiar with it. I think you should post this as a new question.

Comment: Ok! I try ! Thank you, Stefan!